# Whitespaces in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, cygwin, classpath

I am working on a Windows PC and have cygwin on it!
I have organized all my jars under a directory within a few directories!
I am writing a `bash` script to set the `CLASSPATH` by iterating through the directory that is passed as a parameter as follows:

```
for JAR_FILE in `ls *.jar`
do
    CLASSPATH="$DIRECTORY_TO_LOOK_FOR_JARS"/$JAR_FILE:$CLASSPATH
done
```

Whenever there are spaces in the directory that is passed like `/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/user/My Jars` and I run `java -cp $CLASSPATH somepackage.someclass`, it throws an error stating that the class `and` is not found, because the CLASSPATH variable is getting split after `/cygdrive/c/Documents`.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this [article](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2006/12/setting-java-classpath-option-with.html).

You could enclose either the full classpath in double qoutes

```
java -classpath "C:/Documents and Settings/user/project/lib/axis.jar; C:/Documents and Settings/user/project/lib/axis-ant.jar;" TestClient
```

or each jar in your classpath

```
java -classpath "C:/Documents and Settings/user/project/lib/axis.jar"; "C:/Documents and Settings/user/project/lib/axis-ant.jar;" TestClient
```

In your case something like that:

```
for JAR_FILE in `ls *.jar`
do
    CLASSPATH="$DIRECTORY_TO_LOOK_FOR_JARS/$JAR_FILE":$CLASSPATH
done
```

Hard to see, but I moved the closing double qoute.