# Java running a program at command prompt: could not find or load main class

Tags: java, class, command-line, program-entry-point

I am trying to learn how to compile and run using only command lines in Windows. Here is the tree of the directories starting from the root:

```
D:
 ActivityOne
     - classes
         - com
           -wat
             -sampleapp
                -students
                    StudentE.class
                 StudentMasterList.class (Main)
     - src
         -com
           -wat
             -sampleapp
                -students
                    StudentE.java
                 StudentMasterList.java (Main)
```

The thing is that I am now confused as to how to run the program. 
I tried two things, where both returned different errors.

1st try:

```
java -classpath classes StudentMasterList
```

returned:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class StudentMasterList
```

2nd try:

```
java -classpath classes/com/wat/sampleapp StudentMasterList
```

returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StudentMasterList (wrongname: com/wat/sam
pleapp/StudentMasterList)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I got confused after the next tries, any help on how i should run the main class?

Update: I should run all my commands at the `ActivityOne` level.

Comment: @BackSlash ActivityOne is The name of the folder, no its not an android app it is just a trivial program basically. I managed to get it working with your solution! But is there anyway where i can do it at the `ActivityOne` folder only? (Meaning not going into other folders within `ActivityOne` if you may ask)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way is

```
java -classpath D:\ActivityOne\classes com.wat.sampleapp.StudentMasterList
```

In other words, you add the top-level directory to the classpath, and then use the fully-qualified name of your Java class.

Comment: @JerYango: Yes, I'd expect it to.

Comment: Yeah you're right thanks and by the way i forgot to mark it. I am sorry about that sir. Just a quick question though.. If a folder name have some spaces like `C:\Documents and Settings` how do i run it?

Comment: @JerYango: Just enclose the path in quotes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003908/367273