# Error: Could not find or load main class for javac

Tags: java

Trying to follow along here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/index.html

I cannot get the incantation to do step #1 in Java.

I've tried export CLASSPATH=. and export CLASSPATH= but I don't even have a class file yet.

Can someone point in the right direction. Tried most of basic posts already.

```
$uname -a
Linux box  3.19.0-41-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 4 18:18:11 UTC     2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ javac -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

$javac ./hello.java 
Error: Could not find or load main class ..hello.java
$javac ./hello
Error: Could not find or load main class ..hello
$javac hello.java 
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.java
$javac hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello
$javac -cp .  hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello
$javac -d  .  hello
Unrecognized option: -d
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
$java -version 
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

$ cat hello.java 
public class hello

{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: To compile: ```$javac hello.java``` to run: ```$java hello```

Comment: your `javac` seems to invoke `java`. What is the output of `which javac`?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388287/java-running-a-program-at-command-prompt-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: @wero - You were correct!  javac was linked to java. Solution for me was : # rm /etc/alternatives/javac  # ln -s  /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/javac /etc/alternatives/javac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: javac was linked to java.

Solution:

```
rm /etc/alternatives/javac
ln -s /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/javac /etc/alternatives/javac
```